# How can I find out what kinds of actions and URI's a given app package will respond to?

Tags: android, package, android-intent

Say I want to ask the Phone app to dial a number, or the Maps app to display a particular location, or the Navigator app to navigate to a particular place, etc....

Obviously I need to broadcast or send an intent.  But what actions/categories/data URI's do I use?  What will each app recognize and respond to?  This seems like basic information that should be documented somewhere obvious.  But so far I haven't been able to find it.

I did find the PackageManager class, which looks like it could tell me everything I might want to know.  If I take the time to write a package browser app to query it.  Which I quite ready to do, but something so insanely useful must have been written by somebody already.  Why can't I find one?  Am I looking in the wrong places?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For OS operations, most of the `Intents` you seek are documented on [the `Intent` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) (see the Constants table, for the constants prefixed with `ACTION_`, and particularly those described as "Activity Action"). The Javadocs explain what is required for each of those `Intent` actions.

For some of Google's apps, the `Intents` you see are documented in [an appendix in the developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html).

Third party apps should document whatever they consider their public API to be on their own sites.

So, for example, that covers "ask the Phone app to dial a number" (`ACTION_DIAL`) and "Maps app to display a particular location" (`geo:` `Uri`).

It does not cover "Navigator app to navigate to a particular place", because Google wrote that app and decided not to document or support any public API for it. That is Google's decision to make.